# ajax - 2 формы на странице

Tags: jquery, ajax

на странице есть 2 формы, которые делают одно и то же.
в инпутах задан одинаковый класс.

в ajax пишу

```
var name = $('.class').val();
```

работает только с первой формой
как это исправить?

пробовал `$(this)` подставить - не выходит

код выглядит так:

```
$(".subscribe_form").submit(function(){
send_subscribe_form();
return false;
});

function send_subscribe_form() {
var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
var your_name = $(".subscribe_form #popup_subscribe_name").val();
var your_email = $(".subscribe_form .subscribe_email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action' : 'wpestate_ajax_subscribe_popup_form',
            'your_name' : your_name,
            'your_email' : your_email,

        },
        success: function() {
        clearForm();
        show_popup_subscribe_ok();
        },
        error: '',
    });
```

}

Таких формы 2 и 2 инпута с классом `subscribe_email`
Если заполнять вторую форму - то не работает (берет данные с первой)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще нужно больше кода, чтобы расписать ответ. Но суть примерно такова, чтобы тебе необходимо обращаться к определенному инпуту данной формы.

Можешь цепляться за их общую обертку. Например,

```
  $(this).closest('form').find('.class').val();
```

Comment: я меня не выходит $(this) использовать

Answer (score 0):

поменял, чтоб $(this) была возможность использовать. Сделал так:

```
$(".subscribe_form").live('submit', function(event){


var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';


var your_name =  $(this).find('#popup_subscribe_name').val(); 
var your_email = $(this).find('input.subscribe_email').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action' : 'wpestate_ajax_subscribe_popup_form',
            'your_name' : your_name,
            'your_email' : your_email,

        },
        success: function() {
        clearForm();
        show_popup_subscribe_ok();
        },
        error: '',
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Все равно, первая форма отправляет, а вторая (тоже с классом `subscribe_form`) - нет

Comment: `$(this).find('#popup_subscribe_name').val();`  - замените выборку по `id` выпоркой по классу

Comment: Как функции `clearForm();` и `show_popup_subscribe_ok();` узнают с каким куском DOM-а им работать?

Comment: на класс поменял - все равно не работает. Там все равно имя задается только в одной форме из 2ух. По-этому id было.

Comment: clearForm(); и show_popup_subscribe_ok(); - в функциях прописаны селекторы. С этим все ок. success срабатывает, но не отправляет

Comment: Что значит "вторая форма не отправляет"? Покажите html.

Comment: решил проблему тем, что добавил пустой input hidden с классом popup_subscribe_name